# How to make user continue filling the form after allowing access for(facebook, twitter, ...)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, omniauth, omniauth-linkedin

I'm making a project and i'm using RoR as a back-end and angularJS as a front-end, I'm stuck with register using linkedin, I have followed this tutorial [link](http://tgib23.github.io/blog/2016/11/10/how-to-use-omniauth-plus-devise-on-rails5/) and it helped me, but my application needs more information from user to be entered while registering which is not on linkedin, So what i thought about is to redirect_to the sign_up page and attach (auth.uid) parameter to the url (like: https://example/signup?uid=ude3f4J) and make the user fill the rest of needed parameters in the form, Is this the best way to do it, Is (auth.uid) is very important thing that i shouldn't send it in the url? Is (auth.uid) something that i should protect?

Thanks

Comment: I watched this video [Ruby on Rails - Railscasts PRO #235 Devise and OmniAuth (revised)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6tKAUOMzCs&t=90s) and it helped me a lot, I think the answer is sessions or cookies.